# Calling an API in Symfony 2 returns me html and not json

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I thank you in advance for taking time to read my problem that I face.
The execution of a Rest Full API (https://dusupay.com/transactions/check_status/1386/19892016.json) from a browser returns me from json.

Now I need to retrieve the data returned by this API in a controller, but unfortunately, it returns me earlier "text / HTML"

```
use Zeroem\CurlBundle\HttpKernel\RemoteHttpKernel           
$request = Request::create("https://dusupay.com/transactions/check_status/1386/19892016.json");
$remoteKernel = new RemoteHttpKernel();
$response1 = $remoteKernel->handle($request);
return new response ($response1);
```

When i try to change the content type in JSON, I receive nothing more as an answer.

Thanks for the time

Answer (score 3):

Use JsonResponse instead of Response:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

Comment: It looks like a backend of dusupay.com is written in CakePHP and is not maintained by @FOKOTHierry

Comment: @jkucharovic he takes json from dusupay.com (check his given url) and then he returns it as a Response object inside his controller, and then he do not have json inside his application, if he will use JsonResponse he will have json object instead of simple reponse object.

Comment: @Elmsas Oh… my fault – I've misunderstand his question.

Answer (score 0):

You can controll all responses formats for your API by Symfony Format Listener. 
Check this out: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html

Or for some particular route use just simple:

```
return new JsonResponse($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some modifications, the problem was solved

```
        use Zeroem\CurlBundle\HttpKernel\RemoteHttpKernel;
    $request = Request::create("https://dusupay.com/transactions/check_status/1386/19892016.json");

    $remoteKernel = new RemoteHttpKernel();
    $response1 = $remoteKernel->handle($request);
    $data = json_decode($response1->getContent());
    return   new response($data->Response->customer_email);
```